# Sovereign debt market learning resources

Tags: reference-request, government-debt

I'm trying to understand this paper, but I'm having some difficulties in understanding some parts. Is there good quick introduction about how the sovereign debt market works?

The paper is about greek debt 2012 restructure:

http://scholarship.law.duke.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5343&context=faculty_scholarship

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. Which parts are you having trouble with. Ideally please ask each as an individual question so that people can provide quality answers.

Comment: Ok, I just edited the question. I'm would like to know more deeply  how the sovereign market work.

Comment: See Obstfeld and Rogoff, Foundations of International Macroeconomics.